# Adding a break or continue statement for a for in loop

Tags: swift, for-loop, for-in-loop

I have a for in loop which iterates through a number of objects, when it finds a certain value inside the loop I want a popUpViewController to pop up and show some information, then once the user has dismissed the popUpViewController, I then want the iteration to continue and if it again finds another value to pop up again , and so on and so forth until the iteration has finished, this is my code and where I am up to, but I'm not sure how to do it. code:

```
var popUpViewController = PopUpViewControllerSwift(
var results = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]

for result in results {
    if result == 2 {
       self.view.addSubview(self.popUpViewController.view)
       self.addChildViewController(self.popUpViewController)
       self.popUpViewController.setValues(UIImage(named: "Me.png"), messageText: "You have matched with \(usernameOne)!", congratsText: "Snap!")
       self.popUpViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }
}
```

This has been simplified down to get to the point.

Comment: I can guess at the problem... but for the sake of question quality, you should actually explain the actual results this code produces and how this differs from the results you want to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon dismissal of your `PopUpViewControllerSwift` you are going to need to continue on with the computation from the last index.  [You'll need a way to recognize when the popup controller has been dismissed - there are numerous ways to do this in UIKit depending on your specific design.  For example, in `viewDidDisappear()`].  To continue from the last index, define a function that takes that index, does the match, and then recursively calls itself with `index + 1` to continue on.

```
let processFrom : ((index:Int) -> Void)!
processFrom     = {(index:Int) -> Void) in
  if index < results.count {
    let result = results[index]

    if result == 2 {
       // setup view

       // provide the continuation - assumes `onDismiss` is defined
       // as a closure to be used when the view is dismissed.
       self.popupViewController.onDismiss = { processFrom (index + 1) }
    }
    else { processFrom (index + 1) }
  }
}
```

This `processFrom` captures the `results` variable and repeatedly processes element from the `results` based on the provided `index`.

Note: Swift isn't very swift regarding recursive functions; hence the use of `processFrom` as a implicitly unwrapped optional.  Depending on your code, if `processFrom` is a function in a class/struct, then you'll avoid this style just by using `func`.

Comment: Thanks this has kind of helped me achieve what I wanted.